# Add line break after meeting two conditions: Under "x" characters & ending with a comma or period

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am working on a little mini-project.

The goal of the project is to strip the formatting (double spaces, numbers, and line breaks) then output that value with a line break every "x" characters, but making sure it ends with a comma or period.

For example...if I set the character limit to 50 (after the "l" in "until"), I would want it to look like the following. Notice that the example favors the punctuation over the character limit, but it won't add a line break unless you are atleast close to the character limit (I added extra commas to further my explanation):

> "The quick, brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,
>
> until that dog, fell asleep."

instead of (character limit):

> "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog, until
>
> that dog fell asleep."

or (punctuation):

> "The quick,
>
> brown fox jumps over the lazy dog,
>
> until that dog,
>
> fell asleep."

If you want my current code (removing double spaces, numbers, and line breaks) to work off of...

```
<script>
function printText() {
    var inputValue = document.getElementById("paste-text").value;

    function editText() {
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/g, ' ');
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[0-9]/gm, ' ');
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(\s\s\s\s)/gm, ' ');
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/(\s\s)/gm, ' ');
        inputValue = inputValue.trim();
        return inputValue;
    }

    if (inputValue.length > 0) {
        document.getElementById("text-output").innerText = editText();
        document.getElementById("edit-text-output").classList.add("showEdited");
    } 
}
</script>

<section>
    <div class="edit-text-container">
        <div class="edit-text-input">
            <div class="edit-text-paste">
                <h3>Paste Text</h3>
                <div class="edit-text-input-area">
                    <textarea name="paste-text" id="paste-text" rows="6" placeholder="Paste Text Here"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Remove Formatting" onclick="printText()">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="edit-text-output">
            <h3>Your <i>edited</i> Text</h3>
            <div class="edit-text-output-area">
                <textarea readonly id="text-output" rows="6"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<style>
textarea {
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    padding:16px; }

#edit-text-output {
    height:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.5s;}

.showEdited {
    height:185px!important;
    opacity:1!important; }

.edit-text-container {
    justify-content:center;
    text-align:center; }

input[type=submit] {
    margin-top:16px; }
</style>
```

Again, this is for a personal project, so no rush for a solution/no problem if it is not possible.

I have tried doing basic if/else statements via Javascript, but to no avail. I have a basic understanding of jQuery and Javascript, so I could just be limited by my lack of knowledge.

Upon looking up solutions, I figured out how to create a line break at a character limit and create a line break at a punctuation, but for some reason I cannot figure out how to do both with the line break at a punctuation being the favored function.

Answer (score 0):

#### Before you code this next part, make sure your requirement is clear

At the moment, it is internally contradictory.

> a line break every "x" characters, but making sure it ends with a comma or period.

There are several problems with this description of your requirement:

1. I think you want the line break to try and be at a word, don't you? But you haven't mentioned that.
2. What happens if there is a word longer than 50 characters?
3. The statement "making sure" conflicts with the possibility of there being a stretch of 50 characters with no comma or period.

Do you really mean that no line shall be longer than 50 characters? If there is a word longer than 50 characters, must it be split. [Think about what you want to happen if the 50-character word is just before a comma: do you want the comma on a new line or the word split, or the line lengthened to 51 characters. If you want the last of these, then this rule must be reworded.]

#### I suggest laying out the requirements somewhat like this:

1. Start with all the text in the input and an empty string for the output.
2. Build up a line as follows: Find the last space within the first 50 characters of the input
3. If there is such a space: Are there any commas or periods within that first piece of text?

   - If so, find the last comma or period and chop the text there.
   - Otherwise chop at that last space.
4. If there is NO such space: You have a word, or word+punctuation, that is too long. (Specify here what you want done: e.g. chop the word, allow the line to extend, etc.)
5. As a result of steps 2,3 and 4 you will have formed a line of text. Add that to the output and delete it from the input.
6. Repeat steps 2-5 until all done.

#### If the above is what you *wanted* done, then it is a good basis for writing your code

The key is to be clear in what you want. If you can express that *unambiguously*, you can usually code it easily. The problem is that in the non-programming world, most people get away with vagueness in their descriptions and we don't realise it until we come to code things.

Comment: Hey Eureka! Thanks for developing my question further :). The use case is pretty specific, but a good amount of what you said about the question is still valid.